# Edit csv file in Scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I would like to edit csv (more than 500MB) file.
If I have data like

```
ID, NUMBER
A, 1
B, 3
C, 4
D, 5
```

I want to add some extra column like

```
ID, NUMBER, DIFF
A, 1, 0
B, 3, 2
C, 4, 1
D, 5, 1
```

This data also be able in ScSla data type.

(in)Orgin Csv file -> (out)(new csv file, file data(RDD type?))

Q1. Which is best way to treat data?

1. make a new csv file from the original csv file, and then re-open the new csv file to scala data.
2. make new scala data first and make it as csv file.

Q2. Do I need to use 'dataframe' for this? Which library or API should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RDD vs DataFrame**: both are good options. The recommendation is to use DataFrames which allows some extra optimizations behind the scenes, but for simple enough tasks the performance is probably similar. Another advantage of using DataFrames is the ability to use SQL - if you're comfortable with SQL you can just load the file, register it as temp table and query it to perform any transformation. A more relevant advantage of DataFrames is the ability to use [databricks' spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) library to easily read and write CSV files.

Let's assume you will use DataFrames (DF) for now:

**Flow**: sounds like you should

1. Load original file to a DF, call it `input`
2. Transform it to the new DF, called `withDiff`
3. At this point, it would make sense to *cache* the result, let's call the cached DF `result`
4. Now you can save `result` to the new CSV file
5. Use `result` again for whatever else you need

Comment: Thanks It really helped me :)

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the data afterwards, neither DFs or RDDs may be a good match. Your "diff" column needs a linear run through the file and so you gain nothing from the parallel nature of Spark.

Answer (score 3):

A fairly trivial way to achieve that is to use [kantan.csv](http://nrinaudo.github.io/kantan.csv/):

```
import kantan.csv.ops._
import kantan.csv.generic.codecs._
import java.io.File

case class Output(id: String, number: Int, diff: Int) 
case class Input(id: String, number: Int)

val data = new File("input.csv").asUnsafeCsvReader[Input](',', true)
                                .map(i => Output(i.id, i.number, 1))

new File("output.csv").writeCsv[Output](data.toIterator, ',', List("ID", "NUMBER", "DIFF"))
```

This code will work regardless of the data size, since at no point do we load the entire dataset (or, indeed, more than one row) in memory.

Note that in my example code, data comes from and goes to `File` instances, but it could come from anything that can be turned into a `Reader` instance - a URI, a String...

Comment: Oh, I just understood how your DIFF column worked. My example just sticks a random value in there, you'd need to modify it somewhat to diff with the previous element, but you can probably do that with a relatively simple fold.